# How to UpdateModel without some fields?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have ImageUrl in my object. If the entity edited without reference to picture, it's field reset. How I can correctly update object?

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = db.Employes;
        return View(items);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        var item = (id != 0) ? db.Employes.Find(id) : new Employee();

        return View(item );
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0, FormCollection formValues = null, Employee item = null)
    {
        if (id == 0)
            db.Employes.Add(item);
        else
        {
            item = db.Employes.Find(id);
            UpdateModel(item);
        }

    Helpers.FileSave("Image", item, formValues);

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

upd1:

after excludind field from updateModel, I can't add new images:

```
if (id == 0)
        db.Employes.Add(item);
    else
    {
        item = db.Employes.Find(id);
        if (formValues["Image"] != null)
        {
            UpdateModel(item);
            Helpers.FileSave("Image", item, formValues);
        }
        else
        {
            string[] excludeProperties = { "Image" };
            UpdateModel(item, null, null, excludeProperties);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the excludeProperties and includeProperties when calling [UpdateModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470388.aspx#Y0).

In short...

```
string[] includeProperties = { “Name”, “Description”, “Active” };
UpdateModel(myModelView, includeProperties);
```

Comment: Thanks, the property is excluded. It's excluded absolutly - I can't add new pictures))

Answer (score 1):

First don't exclude properties second,In your else part of updated code add the following line

```
item.Image =formValues["Image"]
```

then call the update model